# New Relic on AWS lambda not reading its config file

Tags: python, django, aws-lambda, newrelic

I'm using zappa to deploy a python/django wsgi app to AWS API Gateway and Lambda.

I have all of these in my environment:

```
    NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE: /var/task/newrelic.ini
    NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY: redacted
    NEW_RELIC_ENVIRONMENT: dev-zappa
    NEW_RELIC_STARTUP_DEBUG: "on"
    NEW_RELIC_ENABLED: "on"
```

I'm doing "manual agent start" in my `wsgi.py` as [documented](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/python-agent/installation-configuration/python-agent-integration#manual-integration):

```
import newrelic.agent
# Will collect NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE and NEW_RELIC_ENVIRONMENT from the environment
# Dear god why??!?!
# NB: Looks like this IS what makes it go
newrelic.agent.global_settings().enabled = True
newrelic.agent.initialize('/var/task/newrelic.ini', 'dev-zappa', log_file='stderr', log_level=logging.DEBBUG)
```

I'm **not** using `@newrelic.agent.wsgi_application` since django should be auto-magically detected

I've added a middleware to shutdown the agent before the lambda gets frozen, but the logging suggests that only the first request is being sent to New Relic. Without the shutdown, I get no logging from the New Relic agent, and there are no events in APM.

```
class NewRelicShutdownMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    """Simple middleware that shutsdown the NR agent at the end of a request"""

    def process_request(self, request):
        pass
        # really wait for the agent to register with collector
        # Enabling this causes more log messages about starting data samplers, but only on the first request
        # newrelic.agent.register_application(timeout=10)

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        newrelic.agent.shutdown_agent(timeout=2.5)
        return response

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        pass
        newrelic.agent.shutdown_agent(timeout=2.5)
```

In my `newrelic.ini` I have the following, but when I log `newrelic.agent.global_settings()` it contains the default App name (which did get created in APM) and enabled = False, which led to some of the hacks above (environment var, and just editing `newrelic.agent.global_settings()` before initialize :

```
[newrelic:dev-zappa]                                                                                          
app_name = DEV APP zappa                                                                                      
monitor_mode = true
```

TL;DR - Two questions:

1. How to get New Relic to read it's ini file when it doesn't want to?
2. How to get New Relic to record data for all requests in AWS lambda?

Comment: i'm having similar problems with my newrelic-django-zappa project

Comment: How are you getting Lambda to create `/var/task/newrelic.ini` with your content?

Comment: @kichik It's in the zipfile that zappa uploads. I have confirmed that the file exists at that path, and have read the contents into the logs. I have confirmed that NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE and NEW_RELIC_ENVIRONMENT are populated in the environment. It just seems like they aren't being consumed as expected.

Comment: I'm asking because I find it hard to believe Lambda lets you extract files to the root folder. Are you sure it doesn't exist relative to the source folder on the server?

Comment: Ignore me. I didn't realize Lambda uses `/var/task` all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zappa does not use your wsgi.py file (currently), so the hooks there aren't happening. Take a look at this PR which allows for it: https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/pull/1251

Comment: I wish they would merge already... i've been waiting for NR-Django-Zappa integration to work...

Comment: @davesave It works on my branch: pip install git+http://github.com/aarcro/zappa.git@master#egg=zappa You need steady traffic for data to get reported to NR, and it depends on the fact that your lambda container gets frozen/thawed and not actually relaunched on every request.

Comment: I'm getting traces loaded to New Relic, just keep reloading the slow page a few times/minute for a minute or two.

Comment: The middleware from my question is NOT needed to get NR working. In fact you should NOT use it.